# Check for uninserted cross-references

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, cross-reference

I am using cross-references in Microsoft Word 2016 to provide citations for my exam report, but I am unable to find an easy and handy way to check for any cross-references that I haven't inserted in the text without having to browse through 20+ pages. Is there a way to check this?